# Passing values from MainActivity to a Java_Class that extends Fragment fails

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

To more understand more how `fragments` work, I created a `mainactivity` its layout has one`<fragment>`. and I created two java classes extend `fragment` and each of these classes has its own layout.

In the java class that extends `fragment`, I initailise my views `textview` inside `onActivityCreated()`, and as shown below in the code in the same class, i created two methods `setbtnclicks(int clicks)` and `getbtnclicks()`. From the `mainactivity` i assign number of clicks of a button to `setbtnclicks()` and i try to display the number of clicks on the `textview` of the class that extends `fragment` by calling `getbtnclicks` from inside `onActivivtyCreated()`. But the problem is, this method always displays zero, as if the number of clicks are not incremented.

MainActivtity:

```
//global variable
private int i = 0;
...
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment mSelectedFragment;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn00:    
        mSelectedFragment = new Fragment00();
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment00ID, mSelectedFragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
        mFragment00.setBtnClicks(i);
        i++;
        break;
```

Java_Class "Fragment00"

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated(): "+order);
    order++;
    mTv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment00Tv00);
    mTv.setText("the Button was clicked "+getBtnClicks()+ " time(s)");
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityCreated(): "+getBtnClicks());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i have implemented a more or less same program like yours.The objective was to increment the number of button clicks in both the fragments.Here is the code.Hope it helps:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button btn1,btn2;
int click1=0,click2=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment = null;
         if (v == btn1) {
                // do stuff for button left
             click1++;

             Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                String clickstring1=Integer.toString(click1);
                 bundle.putString("name1",clickstring1 );

             fragment = new FragButton1();


                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);


            }
         if (v == btn2) {
                // do stuff for button right
             click2++;
             Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                String clickstring2=Integer.toString(click2);
             bundle.putString("name2",clickstring2 );
                fragment = new FragButton2();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            }

         if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
         }
         else{
             Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
         }

    }



}
```

**FragButton1.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FragButton1 extends Fragment{

    TextView tv;
public FragButton1(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragbutton1, container, false);
        String strtext=getArguments().getString("name1");
        tv=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_times1);
        tv.setText(strtext);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**FragButton2.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class FragButton2 extends Fragment{

    TextView tv2;
public FragButton2(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragbutton2, container, false);
        tv2=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_times2);
        String strtext=getArguments().getString("name2");
        tv2.setText(strtext);
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Here there are 2 buttons and onclick of a button a new fragment will be launched and the fragment will display the number of times a button is clicked in a textview.

Comment: I thought about using bundle as well, but any idea why it does not works without bundle? another question please, what is the use of "Bundle savedInstanceState" parameter that is passsed to the onActivityCreated if it does not has all the values of the mainActivity that has the `<fragment>`tag

Comment: I always use Bundle to pass data from activity to fragment.I have no idea that why it does not works without bundle.Also  "Bundle savedInstanceState" saves the states of your activity i.e. suppose you want to pass some data onorientationchange from potrait to landscape.Then you can put the things you want to save in savedInstanceState and then you can retrieve your saved data from savedInstanceState through the method public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Answer (score 0):

increment i before the fragment Transaction

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btn00:  
     i++;  
    mSelectedFragment = new Fragment00();
    mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment00ID, mSelectedFragment);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    mFragment00.setBtnClicks(i);

    break;
```

Comment: i did so but i got the same result